# Application Insights throwing neverending exceptions

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, azure-application-insights

When enabled the Application Insights request telemetry middleware, it throws all kinds of exceptions without end. This hasns't been an issue before.

Startup.ConfigureServices configuration:

```
var appInsightsConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddApplicationInsightsSettings(
        developerMode: true,
        instrumentationKey: Configuration["ApplicationInsights:Key"])
    .Build();

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(appInsightsConfiguration);
```

Adding middleware to the beginning of the pipeline:

```
app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
```

We are using 1.0.0 of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`.

Exceptions thrown look something like this:

> {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)}

[image]

[image]

```
{System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)}
```

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the new SDK, created a Web Application in VS2015U3 and followed the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started) guide on GitHub. I was unable to rerpo. Can you share this project somewhere?

Comment: @debugthanks: Thanks for looking into it, but it has stopped happening. I'm not sure if there is any explanation for this, but I'm VERY certain it was due to the Application Insights middleware.

Comment: you might want to use fiddler and see what the exact message in the 400 failure is.  the AI service will (generally) tell you exactly why it is rejecting your data.  you might have some invalid content somehow (or an invalid ikey?)

Comment: also, were the exceptions caught by your code, or were they caught in the AI layer, and you're just seeing them go by?  if this is crashing out into your code, and you have a repro, submit it as an issue on the github repo for the AI aspnetcore package: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore

Comment: They wernt bubbling up to my code. Only caught in AI. I should have mentioned that! I have not been able to reproduce since but will report it if it happens again.